# Selecting only the latest sequence in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that logs down actions in sets that is based on the Secondary and Code, The example below is essentially two actions seperated by sequence number.  My question is how do you get only the latest Sequence set using SQL?

So far, I can get the latest Sequence Number using the query below but I feel it's not the best approach.

```
Select max(SequenceNo) as LatestSequence from tblLogs Where 
1 = (Case when charindex(SecondaryID, @SecondaryID) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Here is the example Table:

```
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| id |  SecondaryID  | SequenceNo |    Code    |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| 23 | ZRHK113100017 |          1 | 0000000001 |
| 24 | ZRHK113100017 |          1 | 0000009460 |
| 25 | ZSHK113100021 |          1 | 0000000001 |
| 26 | ZSHK113100021 |          1 | 0000009460 |
| 27 | ZRHK113100017 |          2 | 0000000001 |
| 28 | ZRHK113100017 |          2 | 0000009460 |
| 29 | ZSHK113100021 |          2 | 0000000001 |
| 30 | ZSHK113100021 |          2 | 0000009460 |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Query should return the following

```
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| id |  SecondaryID  | SequenceNo |    Code    |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| 27 | ZRHK113100017 |          2 | 0000000001 |
| 28 | ZRHK113100017 |          2 | 0000009460 |
| 29 | ZSHK113100021 |          2 | 0000000001 |
| 30 | ZSHK113100021 |          2 | 0000009460 |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Table_1 
WHERE SequenceNo = (SELECT MAX(SequenceNo) FROM dbo.Table_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` together with `ORDER BY ... DESC`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY SequenceNo DESC
;
```

`TOP (1)` will get you the topmost row based on the specified order, `WITH TIES` will instruct the server to additionally return all the rows that have the same `SequenceNo` value as the topmost row.